# How to import boostrap v5 (js + css) into nuxt.js v2.14 with vue v3 project?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vuejs3, bootstrap-5

As of today, *bootstrap-vue* does not support ***vue v3*** and ***bootstrap v5***.

I would like to just **import** bootstrap files into ***nuxt v2.14*** project. Could anyone give me a specific example how to accomplish this?

Since I just started vue/nuxt a week ago I would appreciate help at this point.

P.S. Emphasis on CSS **and** JS.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Add bootstrap 5 css and js files in assets directory under the folder `bootstrap` after downloading them then configure your `nuxt.config.js` :

```
export default {
   ...
     css: ['~/assets/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css'],
     script: [
      {
        src: "~/assets/bootstrap/bootstrap.bundle.min.js",
        type: "text/javascript"
      }
     ]
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 12):

As I installed bootstrap 5 with npm, I didn't want to do it the same way as the accepted answer so maybe this will be helpfull for someone esle:

-About css:
I am used to work with scss so I installed sass loader:

```
npm install --save-dev sass sass-loader@10 fibers
```

Next in the assets folder I created a scss folder with a main.scss file inside. In this file you can import bootstrap css (like that you can even override bootstrap variables, don't forget to import them if you want to do that):

```
@import "~bootstrap";
```

Then in the nuxt.config.js I added this:

```
css: [
    '~/assets/scss/main.scss'
],
```

-The js part was the most tricky but finally it works perfectly:

In the plugins folder, just create a file named bootstrap.js
Just add an import inside:

```
import bootstrap from 'bootstrap'
```

Then in your nuxt.config.js:

```
plugins: [
    {src: '~/plugins/bootstrap.js', mode: 'client'}
],
```

Dont't forget the mode:'client', if not you will get 'document is not defined' error because of server side renderning.

Enjoy :)

Edit: the nuxt js version when I write this: 2.15.3 with bootstrap 5 as well :)

Comment: thx for your contribution. I will give this a try. Btw, why dont' people just use the CDN? Performance wise there's not much of a difference anymore between CDN/local, imho. Just makes it much easier.

Comment: the import in main.scss does not work for me. i use `@import "node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap"` instead;

Comment: Using Nuxt 3. In main.scss I had to **@import "bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss";** instead.

Comment: The import in bootstrap.js does not work for me in Nuxt 3. I have to use `import 'bootstrap/js/index.esm'; export default defineNuxtPlugin(() => { })`