# Nuxt 2 Bootstrap 5 npm run generate build error

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, sass, nuxt.js, sass-loader

I have a nuxt 2 project with bs5, when I run `npm run dev` everything works as expected but when I run `npm run generate` to make static files I receive a `Nuxt Fatal Error Error: Nuxt build error`

```
ERROR in ./assets/scss/main.scss (./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--7-oneOf-1-1!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??ref--7-oneOf-1-2!./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--7-oneOf-1-3!./assets/scss/main.scss)  
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/postcss-loader/src/index.js):
ParserError: Syntax Error at line: 1, column 38
    at D:\repos\bs5\assets\scss\main.scss:6:65128
    at Parser.error (D:\repos\bs5\node_modules\postcss-values-parser\lib\parser.js:127:11)
    at Parser.operator (D:\repos\bs5\node_modules\postcss-values-parser\lib\parser.js:162:20)
    at Parser.parseTokens (D:\repos\bs5\node_modules\postcss-values-parser\lib\parser.js:245:14)
    at Parser.loop (D:\repos\bs5\node_modules\postcss-values-parser\lib\parser.js:132:12)
    at Parser.parse (D:\repos\bs5\node_modules\postcss-values-parser\lib\parser.js:51:17)
    at parse (D:\repos\bs5\node_modules\postcss-custom-properties\index.cjs.js:47:30)
    at D:\repos\bs5\node_modules\postcss-custom-properties\index.cjs.js:333:24
    at D:\repos\bs5\node_modules\postcss\lib\container.js:194:18
    at D:\repos\bs5\node_modules\postcss\lib\container.js:139:18
    at Rule.each (D:\repos\bs5\node_modules\postcss\lib\container.js:105:16)
    at Rule.walk (D:\repos\bs5\node_modules\postcss\lib\container.js:135:17)
    at D:\repos\bs5\node_modules\postcss\lib\container.js:152:24
    at Root.each (D:\repos\bs5\node_modules\postcss\lib\container.js:105:16)
    at Root.walk (D:\repos\bs5\node_modules\postcss\lib\container.js:135:17)
    at Root.walkDecls (D:\repos\bs5\node_modules\postcss\lib\container.js:192:19)
    at transformProperties (D:\repos\bs5\node_modules\postcss-custom-properties\index.cjs.js:330:8)
 @ ./assets/scss/main.scss 4:14-224
 @ ./node_modules/.cache/nuxt/App.js
 @ ./node_modules/.cache/nuxt/index.js
 @ ./node_modules/.cache/nuxt/client.js
 @ multi ./node_modules/@nuxt/components/lib/installComponents.js ./node_modules/.cache/nuxt/client.js

 FATAL  Nuxt build error                                                                                                                                                                                               15:18:26  

  at WebpackBundler.webpackCompile (node_modules\@nuxt\webpack\dist\webpack.js:2127:21)
  at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
  at async WebpackBundler.build (node_modules\@nuxt\webpack\dist\webpack.js:2076:5)
  at async Builder.build (node_modules\@nuxt\builder\dist\builder.js:327:5)
  at async ensureBuild (node_modules\@nuxt\cli\dist\cli-generate.js:145:3)
  at async Object.run (node_modules\@nuxt\cli\dist\cli-generate.js:283:7)
  at async NuxtCommand.run (node_modules\@nuxt\cli\dist\cli-index.js:413:7)
```

Error points to assets\scss\main.scss line 1 `@import "bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";`

I've tried many ways to import bs5 scss, dev build always runs fine, generate always fails.

Also done npm install --save-dev sass sass-loader@10

**Do I need to add some special lines to nuxt.config.js?**

**Is there something wrong with sass/nuxt versions?**

`nuxt.config.js`

```js
export default {
  // Disable server-side rendering: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/ssr-mode
  ssr: false,

  // Target: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-target
  target: 'static',

  // Global page headers: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-head
  head: {
    title: 'bs5',
    htmlAttrs: {
      lang: 'en',
    },
    meta: [
      { charset: 'utf-8' },
      { name: 'viewport', content: 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1' },
      { hid: 'description', name: 'description', content: '' },
      { name: 'format-detection', content: 'telephone=no' },
    ],
    link: [{ rel: 'icon', type: 'image/x-icon', href: '/favicon.ico' }],
  },

  // Global CSS: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-css
  css: [
    '~/assets/scss/main.scss',
  ],

  // Plugins to run before rendering page: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-plugins
  plugins: [
    { src: '~/plugins/bootstrap.client.js' },
  ],

  // Auto import components: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-components
  components: true,

  // Modules for dev and build (recommended): https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-modules
  buildModules: [],

  // Modules: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-modules
  modules: [],

  // Build Configuration: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-build
  build: {},
}
```

Adding these lines to build doesn't solve the issue:

```js
sass: {
  implementation: require('sass')
},
scss: {
  implementation: require('sass')
}
```

And this is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "bs5",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "nuxt",
    "build": "nuxt build",
    "start": "nuxt start",
    "generate": "nuxt generate",
    "lint:prettier": "prettier --check .",
    "lint": "npm run lint:prettier",
    "lintfix": "prettier --write --list-different ."
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "bootstrap": "^5.2.0",
    "core-js": "^3.19.3",
    "nuxt": "^2.15.8",
    "vue": "^2.6.14",
    "vue-server-renderer": "^2.6.14",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.14",
    "webpack": "^4.46.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.3.0",
    "prettier": "^2.5.1",
    "sass": "^1.54.8",
    "sass-loader": "^10.3.1"
  }
}
```

Full repository here: https://github.com/lecano/bs5.git

Comment: Why aren't you using bootstrap-vue here? You don't care about the JS components?

Comment: Also, did you tried that one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65809886/8816585 ? Or some answers on the web?

Comment: @kissu Yes but I need to import sass vars to customize bs5

Answer (score 1):

Solved: downgrade sass to "^1.39.0". Sass 1.4x.x and 1.5x.x fails.

```
npm i --save-dev sass@^1.39.0
```

Not sure if it's a webpack or sass mismatch but now I can run `npm run generate` without issues.

I wish I could use nuxt 3 for this project.